# How to get wp social login form by using <?php wp_login_form(); ?>

Tags: wordpress

I am using wp social login plugin for client login but it doesn't show social login options.
i am using this command.`

```
<?php wp_login_form(); ?>
```

please help me out.

Comment: Try with this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout

Comment: thanks dingo_d for respond actually i am working on someone custom theme the person made 2 sidebar on the right sidebar he embed login form and i am using the same widget on the login slide panel but it doesn't show social login option. the site link is www.amoraview.com if you can help me so please help me i am in trouble

Comment: There is a login button in the upper right corner, when you click it, a login panel opens and on the left there is a log in button (not sure why). Then when you click it, you get sent to a wp-login (http://www.amoraview.com/wp-login.php), and there you can see your social login plugin. You'd need to see the documentation of the plugin for details.

Comment: Thanks dingo_d its work there is a problem in theme sidebar option i resolved it now it working

Comment: Great! Good luck with the rest :)